# Converting Access PIVOT query to Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot-table, crosstab

I have an MS Access PIVOT query which needs to be migrated to Oracle 11g.

```
    TRANSFORM Format(Sum(tblOrderLine.ItemQtyCur), '#0.0') AS [The Value]

SELECT  tblOrderLine.OrderStatus, tblOrderLine.OrdNo, tblOrderLine.OrdlNo, Format(Sum(tblOrderLine.ItemQtyCur), '#0.0')  As SumConfQty

FROM tblOrder INNER JOIN (tblOrderLine LEFT JOIN tblArticle ON tblOrderLine.ItemId = tblArticle.ArtNo) ON tblOrder.OrdNo = tblOrderLine.OrdNo

GROUP BY  tblOrderLine.OrderStatus, tblOrderLine.OrdNo, tblOrderLine.OrdlNo

PIVOT tblOrderLine.LastDate
```

I am unable to convert this to oracle 11g PIVOT.

Can any one help me with this....

Edit :

Will it b like this.....

```
WITH pivot_data AS (
SELECT  tblOrderLine.OrderStatus, tblOrderLine.OrdNo, tblOrderLine.OrdlNo, Format(tblOrderLine.ItemQtyCur, '#0.0')  As SumConfQty
FROM tblOrder INNER JOIN (tblOrderLine LEFT JOIN tblArticle ON tblOrderLine.ItemId = tblArticle.ArtNo) ON tblOrder.OrdNo = tblOrderLine.OrdNo
GROUP BY  tblOrderLine.OrderStatus, tblOrderLine.OrdNo, tblOrderLine.OrdlNo
)
SELECT * FROM pivot_data
PIVOT XML (
Format(Sum(tblOrderLine.ItemQtyCur), '#0.0')
FOR tblOrderLine.LastDate
IN (
SELECT  tblOrderLine.LastDate
FROM tblOrder INNER JOIN (tblOrderLine LEFT JOIN tblArticle ON tblOrderLine.ItemId = tblArticle.ArtNo) ON tblOrder.OrdNo = tblOrderLine.OrdNo
GROUP BY  tblOrderLine.OrderStatus, tblOrderLine.OrdNo, tblOrderLine.OrdlNo
)
);
```

Comment: Nothing yet, dont know how to convert it

Answer (score 1):

Your `PIVOT` syntax should be something like this:

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT tblOrderLine.OrderStatus, 
        tblOrderLine.OrdNo, 
        tblOrderLine.OrdlNo, 
        tblOrderLine.ItemQtyCur,
        tblOrderLine.LastDate
    FROM tblOrder 
    INNER JOIN tblOrderLine 
        ON tblOrder.OrdNo = tblOrderLine.OrdNo
    LEFT JOIN tblArticle 
        ON tblOrderLine.ItemId = tblArticle.ArtNo 
) x
pivot
(
    sum(ItemQtyCur)
    for LastDate in (yourDatesHere)
) p
```

If you want to use `PIVOT XML`, then the syntax would be similar to this:

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT tblOrderLine.OrderStatus, 
        tblOrderLine.OrdNo, 
        tblOrderLine.OrdlNo, 
        tblOrderLine.ItemQtyCur,
        tblOrderLine.LastDate
    FROM tblOrder 
    INNER JOIN tblOrderLine 
        ON tblOrder.OrdNo = tblOrderLine.OrdNo
    LEFT JOIN tblArticle 
        ON tblOrderLine.ItemId = tblArticle.ArtNo 
) x
pivot XML
(
    sum(ItemQtyCur) as SumItemQtyCur
    for (LastDate) in (SELECT DISTINCT LastDate FROM tblOrderLine)
) p
```

Here is a reference article about Oracle Pivots:

[pivot and unpivot queries in 11g](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506)

Comment: @NikhilGupta can you create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8) with some sample data for each table?